# Test Ag Grid with react-testing-library: implement click on cell

Tags: ag-grid, react-testing-library, react-functional-component

I want to test a functional component that uses AG grid, in particular, I need to implement a click on AG grid cell. For tests I use react-testing-library. But the thing is, cell nodes are not visible and when I did `screen.debug` it didn't show any html related to grid cells.

At first I thought that AG grid just didn't yet mount on the dom, but its other elements, like rows and rowGroups are found by selectors, so probably this is not the case.
Could you please give any idea why AG grid cells are not visible and what should I do to access them?

Comment: You may have to wait till method onGridyReady is invoked.

Comment: @SteveTomlin, I tried that, but unfortunately with no luck. Maybe I did something wrong, but why then the rest of the grid is shown without any waiting?

Comment: Maybe provide a small codesandbox. Sometimes thst in itself can help expose the problem. Or a very small github example dedicated to this problem

Comment: @SteveTomlin, I almost posted an example component and test, but with example mock all gridcells are printed. I do not have the right to post the original code and its's also has lots of unrelated (although, now not so sure) code. I'll think about providing an example.
Also, I implemented waiting for ag grid in the test, exactly as it was suggested in the official guide (https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/testing/) for functional component, but still with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `suppressColumnVirtualisation` property to your `AgGridReact` component?

Comment: Yes, it was one of the first things I did, but unfortunately, it did not change anything. Maybe there are combinations of factors...

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question but maybe this response can help someone else that land in this question as I did. I was able to test the cell click with react-testing-library using the following code:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByRole('grid')).toBeInTheDocument());
//the aria-rowcount depends on the number of rows to render, I only pass 1
await waitFor(async () => expect(await screen.findByRole('grid')).toHaveAttribute('aria-rowcount', '3'));
await waitFor(async () => expect(screen.getByText('some text')).toBeInTheDocument());

await waitFor(async () => fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('some text')), {timeout: 5000});
```